# Conditional formatting based on a date OR if another cell is blank

Tags: excel-2010

I'm trying to set up conditional formatting to change the color of cells in column A if the date is more than 1 day before today's date AND the corresponding cell in column F is blank (ie, A2 and F2). If there is a date in column F, then I do not want the cell in column A to change color. I also want to copy a variation of this formatting into column F (if the date is older than 3 days before today's date AND the corresponding cell in column G is empty), and column G (corresponding with column H). If possible, I'd also like to format column I to change color if the date is today's date, or earlier, but to not change color if there is a date in column H.

All the previous formatting I've attempted has either changed the color of all the blank cells in the column, or will only work for one of the conditions (whichever is at the top of the list), or not at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I tried to include an image for reference, but it won't allow me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cell, A4, I have created the following formula, which only triggers if the date is older than yesterday and the cell F4 is blank.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A4)),A4<TODAY()-1,ISBLANK(F4))
```

Comment: Great! I had to play with the formula a bit to get it working how I wanted, but it's all sorted now. Thank you!